# How to get a Product Variation Custom Field to work along other plugins?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I get this code (see below) to create a Product Variation Custom Field. It works just fine. Now I need to use the WP All Import Pro plugin to import Products from a csv file. This plugin allow to create the importation task by mapping the information in the csv to the fields of Product and Product Variation.

**Problem:** thing is that the new created Product Variation Custom Field is not visible for the WP All Import plugin. I mean, this new field is not listed when I do the mapping of the data be imported.

My assumption is that this code fails to create some data in the database to make this field available for other module.

How can I get this to work properly

I also attached a capture of the WP All Import page where the field should be visible.

```
/*******************************
add custom fields to product variations 
*********************************/
// regular variable products
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'add_to_variations_metabox', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_product_variation', 20, 2 );


/*
 * Add new inputs to each variation
 *
 * @param string $loop
 * @param array $variation_data
 * @return print HTML
 */
function add_to_variations_metabox( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $custom = get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_custom', true ); ?>

        <div class="variable_custom_field">
            <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label><?php echo __( 'MY CUSTOM FIELD:', 'plugin_textdomain' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" size="5" name="variation_custom_data[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>

    <?php 

}

/*
 * Save extra meta info for variable products
 *
 * @param int $variation_id
 * @param int $i
 * return void
 */
function save_product_variation( $variation_id, $i ){

    // save custom data
    if ( isset( $_POST['variation_custom_data'][$i] ) ) {
        // sanitize data in way that makes sense for your data type
        $custom_data = ( trim( $_POST['variation_custom_data'][$i]  ) === '' ) ? '' : sanitize_title( $_POST['variation_custom_data'][$i] );
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_custom', $custom_data );
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Though this question was initially asked 2 years ago. I found a solution in 2020. I hope this will help anyone who's still looking for a solution.

Please go to All Products and at the top where it says Add New Product you should see two more buttons "Import" and "Export". Click on Export and you will see an option of checkbox "Yes, export all custom meta" Please check this potion and all your custom fields even in variations will be exported.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WP ALL IMPORT has this section coded into their files. They have not provide any hook or filter to add fields to this section.

The most important thing here is that WP ALL IMPORT has thought is like this :

As all the Meta for a particular variation is added finally to the post meta table. Which will be retrieved as by get_post_meta. Just like the custom fields. So in order to attach meta to the variation, you can just another Custom Fields with the Name as the name which the actual meta is stored with and with the value you want the variation to be. Just check the image attached. Refer - http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/custom-fields/theme-plugin-fields/

[image]

Comment: Problem is tha the custom field is not shown as a Custom Field at all. I think  that what you say suits to Product Custom Fields but not for Product Variation Custom Fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked almost a year ago but I have been trying to figure out this exact issue out for quite some time now. But in the end I managed to find a workaround that at least will allow you to get that data into the variation instead of the main parent product:

1) In the WpAllImport Wordpress Addon you will be able to see a "variations" tab as shown in your screenshot. Click on this.

2) On this page you will once again not be able to see any custom fields you have made for variations HOWEVER there is a **product attributes** section.

3) If you add your variation as an attribute and uncheck "Show in variations" and "Taxonomy" and "Is Visible" then you can store your data in an attribute.

4) After the import you should be able to see you data in the attribute, if you know some programming you can even write a script to then loop through all variations and copy this data over to a custom field.

I know it's not much, but for my purposes I was at least able to save the data in the variation which I then used late in a product export plugin.

Hope that helps!